# Magento sort attribute - get url

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, filter, sorting

For filtering attributes, I have used the `geturl()` method. In order to get the required url, a client-side input type component should use in order to call the server and activate the required filtering via the defined controller.
For attribute :

```
$items = $this->_filter->getItems();
    $filterValues = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
                   $filterValueData["filter_url"] = $item->getUrl();
}
```

How can this please be performed for a sorting attribute for example price or date ?
I currently create those urls manually - for example : `?creation_date=asc`

Answer (score 0):

You'd take a look to **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar**

Sorter urls, in a default installation, use attribute codes, you can check this by calling

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
```

Check **catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml**, so you can see how Magento gets available orders, and their urls

```
    <div class="sort-by">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```